# WhatsApp unable to open

Tags: whatsapp

Since yesterday afternoon I am unable to launch my WhatsApp on Lumia 640. I tried reinstalling and even factory reset the phone but it's not opening. Please help me fix it.

Comment: What version of OS is your phone running? Did you get any error message?

Comment: Am Running Windows 10 os and have not being receiving any error messages just refuse to open please help me fix because am missing a lot of information so please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps to fix your connection. They're from the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/22014642/?category=5245260) and are written for Android, but the basic steps should apply to Windows phones as well.

> - Restart your phone, or turn it off and on.
> - Update WhatsApp to the latest version available on Google Play.
> - Open your phone's Settings app > More > and turn Airplane mode on and off.
> - Open your phone's Settings app > Data usage > and make sure that Cellular data is turned on

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your time and date of your phone is correct.